# Compare byte value to bytea column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, bytea

Is there a way to compare a single `byte` value to a `bytea` field in PostgreSQL?

For example: I have a `bytea` field with the value `\x11AA22BB`. The comparison to a `byte` value of `AA` should be true while the comparison to a `byte` value of `1A` should be false.

The only way I see is to extract each `byte` from the `bytea` column separately with something like `get_byte(string, offset)` and check each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a bytea field with the value \x11AA22BB. The comparison to a
>   byte value of AA should be true

It seems you're looking for the [`position`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html) function, knowing that it will return 0 if the byte is not contained in the string:

```
select position('\xAA'::bytea in '\x11AA22BB') > 0 AS contained;

 contained 
-----------
 t
```

If the byte value is stored in an integer, `set_byte` can be used to place it into a bytea:

```
select position(set_byte('\x00', 0, 170) in '\x11AA22BB') > 0;
```